# Prove that ${\tau _1} = {\tau _2}$ if and only if $x \in V \subseteq U$ and $x \in U \subseteq V$

Tags: general-topology

I'm struggling with the following question:

> Let $X$ be any set. Let ${\mathcal{B}_1}$ be a base of $\left( {X,{\tau _1}} \right)$, and ${\mathcal{B}_2}$ a base of $\left( {X,{\tau _2}} \right)$. Prove that ${\tau _1} = {\tau _2}$ **if and only if** for every $x \in X$ and any $U \in {\mathcal{B}_1}$ with $x \in U$ there exists a $V \in {\mathcal{B}_2}$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$; and for every $V \in {\mathcal{B}_2}$ with $x \in V$ there exists a $U \in {\mathcal{B}_1}$ such that $x \in U \subseteq V$.

I have no problem proving the first direction, meaning assuming that ${\tau _1} = {\tau _2}$, then $x \in V \subseteq U$ and $x \in U \subseteq V$.

How do I go about proving the converse?

To prove ${\tau _1} \subseteq {\tau _2}$:

How should I show that $U \in {\tau _2}$? Can I say that since $U \in {\tau _1}$ and $\exists V \in {\mathcal{B}_2}$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$, then since ${\mathcal{B}_2}$ is a base of $\left( {X,{\tau _2}} \right)$, there is a family ${\left( {{B_i}} \right)_I}$ in ${\mathcal{B}_2}$ such that $U = \bigcup\limits_I {{B_i}}$. Therefore $U \in {\tau _2}$ and ${\tau _1} \subseteq {\tau _2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $U \in \tau_1$ then you know that **for every** $x \in U$ there exists $V \in \tau_2$ such that $x \in V \subset U$.

To put this another way, if we let $\mathcal V = \{V \in \tau_2 \mid V \subset U\}$ then we know that for every $x \in U$ there exists $V \in \mathcal V$ such that $x \in V$.

From this it follows that $\bigcup_{V \in \mathcal V} V = U$. And therefore, since each $V$ is an element of $\tau_2$, and since the union of any collection of elements of $\tau_2$ is also an element of $\tau_2$, it follows that $U \in \tau_2$.

Comment: Should the first line be $x \in V \subseteq U$, and not $x \in V \in U$ at the end right?

Comment: Yes, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the condition, i.e.

$$\forall x \in X: \forall U \in \mathcal{B}_1: x \in U \to (\exists V \in \mathcal{B}_2: x \in V \subseteq U)$$

basically says (pun intended) that all $U \in \mathcal{B}_1$ are open in $\tau_2$ (all points in it are $\tau_2$-interior points due to the existence of the $V \in \tau_2$), which implies $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ (as $\tau_2$ is closed under unions and every member of $\tau_1$ is a union of sets from $\mathcal{B}_1 \subseteq \tau_2$).

The second part (with the roles reversed) gives the reverse inclusion, by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

We show that $\mathcal{B}_1 \subseteq \tau_2$, so pick $U \in \mathcal B_1$. If $U = \varnothing$, then $U \in \tau_2$ and we are done. If $U$ is non-empty, let $x \in U$. By hypotheses, there exists $V_x \in \mathcal{B}_2$ such that $x \in V_x \subseteq U$. It is easy to see that
$$U = \bigcup_{x \in U} V_x,$$
and so, $U \in \tau_2$ since each $V_x$ is in $\tau_2$. Thus, $\mathcal{B}_1 \subseteq \tau_2$, as desired. Now, in order to prove that $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$, pick $U \in \tau_1$. As $\mathcal{B}_1$ is a basis for $\tau_1$, there exists $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal B_1$ such that
$$U = \bigcup \, \mathcal U.$$
By the latter, $\mathcal U \subseteq \tau_2$, and it follows that $U \in \tau_2$.

Comment: Why after finding that $U \in \tau_2$ do you not conclude that $ \tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ as Lee Moser did below?

Comment: Well, I pick $U \in \tau_1$ and I find out $U \in \tau_2$. It follows that $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$.